# How to lock down Chromebook settings

Tags: chromebook

i currently have a chromebook to trial in our department, but i want to lock down a user from going into settings and changing anything.
so basically all they can do is search on a certain webpage.
Guest user access has been disabled so we will not be using it.

is this able to be done?

Answer (score 0):

Not a great solution but close: there are kiosk app in the Chrome web store.  The usual idea is users see nothing but a single default home page.

If your company uses a GSuite domain you have more options but the last time I looked at the admin console a few months ago there was no option to lock out settings changes.

Reset Settings in Settings resets browsing settings and files.  I don't think it resets volume, screen brightness, bookmarks etc.